# How does last_simple work in Actions Builder?

Tags: actions-on-google

I assume any last_simple/text: will be displayed immediately before the Intent (in my case) transitions to a new Scene. I see another post on StackOverFlow that says that functionality is limited to a phone. I am unable to get last_simple/text: from my intent Prompt to display in Test Mode on a phone simulator. Is it limited to a physical phone?

Answer (score 1):

A response prompt can consist of two simple responses, and content.

- The content (Card, Table, List, etc.) is displayed to the user.
- The first simple response (first_simple) is read out first.
- The second simple response (last_simple) is read out last.

last_simple works **across all devices**, including simulator and physical devices.

For more information on how to send a response prompt, visit our [Prompts](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts) documentation.

Comment: It must be a bug then. last_simple is never read out, ever, under any circumstances.